# Javascript calculation function is not returning values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The attached javascript function should use the values from the two input ranges and the value from the initialrate cells in the table. It should then calculate total repayment of a loan.

This is not being outputted in the 'td repayment' cell's as expected?

```js
< script >

  var repayment = function() {

  };

document.repaymentcalc.amount.onchange = repayment;

};

makeSomething();

function makeSomething() {
  $('tbody tr').each(function(idx, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    var initialRateCell = $row.find('td')[1];
    var repaymentCell = $row.find('td')[3];
    var rate = parseFloat($(initialRateCell).html());
    var repaymentVal = computeRepayment(rate);
    $(repaymentCell).html(repaymentVal.repayment);
  });
}
$("#calcform :input").change(function() {
  makeSomething();
});

function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.amount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate, 10) / 36500;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10);


var repayment = (x * y * z) + x;

return {
    repayment: '£' + repayment.toFixed(2),
};
}

< /script>
```

```html
</head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<form name="repaymentcalc" id="calcform" action="">

  Amount
  <input id="amount" type="range" min="0" max="2500" step="50" value="100" style="width: 150px">Term
  <input id="numberpayments" type="range" min="0" max="420" step="30" value="30" style="width: 150px">


</form>

<table id="mortgagetable">

  <thead>

    <tr class="producthd">
      <th class="lenderhd">Lender</th>
      <th class="initialratehd">% p.a. fixed</th>
      <th class="rateshd">% APR</th>
      <th class="repaymenthd">Total Repayment</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr class="product">
      <td class="lender">Bank1</td>
      <td class="initialrate">285</td>
      <td class="rates">1204.39</td>
      <td class="repayment"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="lender">Bank2</td>
      <td class="initialrate">292</td>
      <td class="rates">1221.5</td>
      <td class="repayment"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="lender">Bank3</td>
      <td class="initialrate">292</td>
      <td class="rates">1295</td>
      <td class="repayment"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product">
      <td class="lender">Bank4</td>
      <td class="initialrate">128</td>
      <td class="rates">1221.5</td>
      <td class="repayment"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: To return a value from a function, you need a `return` statement in it.

Comment: First off, you repayment function is empty. So of course nothing will happen.

Secondly, you local variable repayment in function computePayment is local so it drops off at the end of call.

Comment: Also your code as posted is not syntactically correct, so it won't do anything until you fix that. Check the developer console.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine until I tried to update the maths in the var repayment? I have not amended ANY other code, and now it just doesn't output anything to the td class='repayment" cells?

Comment: I have updated the snippet to return repayment from the function, but it is still not working? What have I overlooked in the syntax please?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function computeRepayment(rate) {
   var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.amount.value, 10);
   var y = parseInt(rate, 10) / 36500;
   var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10);


  return (x * y * z) + x;
}
```

and your function repayment looks empty

Comment: So why does this not work? var repayment = (x * y * z) + x;

    return {
        repayment: '£' + repayment.toFixed(2),
    };
}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return statement in your function. You need to return your value if you want to use it:

```
function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.amount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate, 10) / 36500;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10);

  var repayment = (x * y * z) + x;

  return repayment // to return your value
}
```

You have a few mistakes in your code. There is a empty function `repayment` and other not right looking stuff. Better check your code again before asking detailed questions.

E.g.:

line 6: Remove **};**

Comment: Have checked and updated the snippet so the function repayment returns the value, but it still doesn't work? Any pointers please?

Comment: Like  i that, you have a few bugs in your code. Look what is getting called and where your code fails. Log your stuff and debug correctly.

Comment: Well I cant understand why it worked previously if there are bugs that make it fail?

Comment: I doubt your code worked without the return statement

Answer (score 0):

To actual get a return from function you need to `return` a value.

As you can see on this simple example:

```
function multiplyTwoNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo){
   var result = numberOne * numberTwo;
   return result; // Here you can see how the value is returned.
}
console.log(multiplyTwoNumbers(5,3); // Here we log the returned value.
```

In your case I think you should return the `repayment` variable.

```
function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.amount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate, 10) / 36500;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10);

  var repayment = (x * y * z) + x;

  return repayment; // here you can see that your value is now returned
}
```

Comment: Can you see why my updated snippet does not work then please? I have returned a value, but it still does not show anything in the td cells?